# Django - ModelForm custom required message

Tags: python, django

I want to override my required message but my code is not working.

Can someone help me?

Here's what I got:

**models. py**

```
class grupos(models.Model):
    nombre_grupo = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre_grupo

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_grupo
```

**forms.py**

```
class gruposModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = grupos
        fields = ["nombre_grupo"]



        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(gruposModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['nombre_grupo'].error_messages = {'required': 'custom required message'}
```

**Thanks in advance!!!**

Answer (score 4):

Looks like indentation is the issue. `__init__` shouldn't be a method of `Meta` class, it should be a method of `gruposModelForm`. Like this:

```
class gruposModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = grupos
        fields = ['nombre_grupo']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(gruposModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['nombre_grupo'].error_messages = {'required': 'custom required message'}
```

Also, `GruposModelForm` is the preferred way of naming such a class according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).